# Bit manipulation of chars in Java or C?

Tags: java, c, bit-manipulation, bit, des

I am a student trying to implement the DES algorithm.
I have a choice of 2 languages: C & Java.
I did understand the algorithm, but am stuck at the very beginning as to manipulation of the key.

Here's the problem.
In DES, we have a 64-bit key (8 chars in C and 4 in Java, although I can cast the char to byte to get only the ASCII part), of which every 8th bit is a parity bit and needs to be stripped to make it a 56-bit key and do further processing. I have thought about this for long, but cannot find a way to strip every 8th bit and store the result in another char array (in Java as well as C).
I tried using the `java.util.BitSet class`, but got confused.

Any suggestions as to how can I remove every 8th bit and concat adjacent bytes(Java) or chars(C) to get the 56 bit key?

I am aware of the bit operations and shifting, but for the specific example:
Suppose I have an 16 bit key: `1100 1001 1101 1000`.
I need to remove the 8th and 16th bit, making the key: `1100 100 1101 100`.

If I declare 2 bytes, how do I truncate the 8th bit and append the 9th bit to it, making the first byte: `1100 1001`

So, what I need help with is how do I, replace 8th bit with 9th bit, replace 16th bit with 17th bit and so on to derive a 56-bit key from 64-bit key?

If someone can explain it to me, I might probably be able to implement it regardless of language.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "and I 4 in Java".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you can manipulate bits with the bitwise operators, such as `&` and `|`, as well as the bitshift operators `<<` and `>>`.

For instance, to turn off the high bit of a given byte, you can do this.

```
char c = 0xBF;  // initial value is bit pattern 10111111
c &= 0x7F;      // perform AND against the bit pattern 01111111
                // final value is bit pattern 00111111 (0x3F)
```

Does that make sense?
Obviously, you need to be able to convert from a bit pattern to hex, but that's not too hard.

You can use similar masking to extract the bits you want, and put them in an output buffer.

**Update:**

You have 64 bits (8 bytes) of input, and want 56 bits (7 bytes) of output.

Let's represent your input as the following, where each letter represents a single bit
The 'x' bits are the ones you want to throw away.

```
xAAAAAAA xBBBBBBB xCCCCCCC xDDDDDDD xEEEEEEE xFFFFFFF xGGGGGGG xHHHHHHH
```

So you want your final answer to be:

```
AAAAAAAB BBBBBBCC CCCCCDDD DDDDEEEE EEEFFFFF FFGGGGGG GHHHHHHH
```

So in C, we might have code like this:

```
unsigned char data[8] = {/* put data here */};

// chop off the top bit of the first byte
data[0] <<= 1;

// the bottom bit of data[0] needs to come from the top data bit of data[1]
data[0] |= (data[1] >> 6) & 0x01;

// use similar transformations to fill in data[1], data[2], ... data[6]
// At the end, data[7] will be useless
```

Of course this is not optimized at all, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful of 16-bit chars in Java.  Many methods only convert the lower 8 bits.  Read the documentation carefully.  It is more usual to treat a cryptographic key as a a `byte[]` in Java due to the stronger typing than in C.

As to the parity bits, check through the DES algorithm carefully and see where they are used.  That should give you a hint as to what you need to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

I can briefly tell about a way....i will explain further if required...

Right shift all the 8 chars by 1 ie c1 = c1>>1 etc

Multiplyc1 with the total number of bytes (ie56) ie c1 * 0x0000000000 (not sure how  many zeros)

Then, add 0x0000+ to next chars ie c2 = c2 + 0x0000; c3 = c3 + 0x000000 so on (Keep adding 2 0s for proceeding chars)

Now, start adding c1 + c2 + c3.......

The idea here is that, first fill in the number with zeros and start adding teh other chars so that they keep lying properly

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
34 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   (c1 = c1>>1) . Here c1=0x34, c2=0x67
00 67 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   (c2 = c2>>1)
so on...............
```

Add teh above;
I hope this will help.

Comment: Let me know if you are still looking for the solution...however I can only provide the solution in C.

Answer (score 0):

@jwd, @jscode
Thanks a lot for your help.
To jwd: I got the idea from your code. Seemed pretty simple logic after I read it..  :-) Wonder why I didnt think of that.
Well, I did polish your idea a little bit and it works fine now in Java.
If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.
THANKS..
P.S.: The testing part is very primitive. I print the bit values. I did it manually for a couple of examples and used the same as input and it works fine.

=============================================

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter an 8 char key: ");
        String input;
        try {
            // get key, key.length()>=8 chars
            input = br.readLine();
            if (input.length() < 8) {
                System.out.println("Key < 8B. Exiting. . .");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            // java char has 16 bits instead of 8 bits as in C,
            // so convert it to 8 bit char by getting lower order byte &
            // discarding higher order byte
            char[] inputKey = input.toCharArray();
            byte[] key64 = new byte[8];
            byte[] key56 = new byte[7];

            // consider only first 8 chars even if input > 8
            for (int counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++)
                key64[counter] = (byte) inputKey[counter];

            System.out.print("\n$$ " + new String(key64) + "  $$\n");

            // converting 64bit key to 56 bit key
            for (int counter = 0; counter < KEY_LENGTH - 1; counter++) {
                key64[counter] = (byte) (key64[counter] >>> 1);
                key64[counter] = (byte) (key64[counter] << 1);
            }

            for (int counter = 0; counter < KEY_LENGTH - 1; counter++) {
                key56[counter] = (byte) (key64[counter] << counter);
                key56[counter] = (byte) (key56[counter] | (key64[counter + 1] >>> (KEY_LENGTH - 1 - counter)));
            }

            /*Conversion from 64 to 56 bit testing code
             System.out.println(new String(key56));

            System.out.println();
            for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < 7; counter1++) {
                for (int counter2 = 7; counter2 >= 0; counter2--) {
                    System.out.println(key56[counter1] & (1 << counter2));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }*/

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the first step for DES has been accomplished - Converting 64 bit key to a 56 bit one by removing every 8th bit..!!